# UIViewController on top of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add custom `UIViewController` on top of everything but not covering full screen (basically popover), like this:

```
- (void) displayPopoverController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; 
   [self.view addSubview:content.view];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          
}
```

Everything works, but unfortunately it is underneath the navigation bar. So I decided to add `UIViewController` to the navigation controller like this:

```
- (void) displayPopoverController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    [self.navigationController addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self.navigationController];
}
```

It worked, but there are 2 problems:

1) `viewWillAppear` is not called when I add popover (only `viewDidLoad` is called)

2) If I change orientation, my popover receives notification and adjusts to new orientation, but `UIViewController` behind it does not. It will only update its view after I remove popover.

Is there any way to fix 1 and 2? Maybe there is better approach(I don't want to use `UIPopoverController` with custom `UIPopoverBackgroundView`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to add custom UIViewController on top of everything but not covering full screen

If you can confine yourself to iOS 7, your problems are over. You can use `presentViewController:` and a custom transition to do exactly what you are trying to do. This, in my view, is the *most important* new feature of iOS 7: you can present a view controller's view only partially covering the main interface.

See my book; for the particular example code from the book, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p304customPresentedAnimation2/ch19p620customPresentedAnimation2/ViewController2.m

Plus I've now posted a single project at https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7. It shows how to make a view controller presented view that only partially covers the interface, plus it demonstrates that device rotation works correctly for all visible views (i.e. what's in front and what's visible behind).

Comment: @Skyler that's a very different (and irrelevant) thing. I'm talking about the same thing as Xeieshan's answer.

Comment: @sash No problem. Thanks for the tick mark. This is a really great (and revolutionary) feature of iOS 7 and yet I suspect that its importance not widely appreciated. But, as the sample code shows, it's really easy to use!

Answer (score 3):

IMO you should make a custom transition and present UIViewController modally.

You can get help on Custom UIViewController transition here :  http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/